# SQL: Finding averages and grouping by two parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

```
ID   Year   Month   Price
001  1990    JAN      6
001  1990    FEB      8
             ...
001  1990    DEC      4
001  1991    JAN      7
      ...
001  2000    DEC      6
002  1990    JAN      7
...
```

Given a table formatted like the one above, how can you find the average yearly price for each item (of each year)? So for example, I'd like to have a new table that looks like:

```
ID   Year   Avg_price
001  1990     7
001  1991     12
      ...
002  1990     11
...
```

I've tried the following code:
    **SELECT** ID, Year, **AVG**(Price)
    **FROM** DATA
    **GROUP BY** ID, Year

But end up getting 0 for each of the averages. The ordering seems to be working correctly though, so I'm not sure why this is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: It turns out there was nothing wrong with my SQL code at all. I guess the answer was simply a bug. Thanks for all your replies, everyone.

Comment: Your SQL looks fine to me!

Comment: What data type is `Price`?

Comment: Another idea: Does `SELECT Price, COUNT(*) FROM DATA GROUP BY Price ORDER BY Price` return any non-numeric, negative, or zero values?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL looks fine to me (Checked with MS SQL).

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4aae/1)

Please doublecheck with MySQL. ;-)